# Using response data from one scenario to another

Tags: automated-tests, karate

With Karate, I'm looking to simulate an end-to-end test structure where I do the following:

1. Make a GET request to specific data
2. Store a value as a `def` variable
3. Use that information for a separate scenario

This is what I have so far:

```
Scenario: Search for asset
    Given url "https://foo.bar.buzz"
    When method get
    Then status 200
    * def responseItem = $.items[0].id // variable initialized from the response
Scenario: Modify asset found
    Given url "https://foo.bar.buzz/" + responseItem
    // making request payload
    When method put.....
```

I tried reading the documentation for reusing information, but that seemed to be for more in-depth testing.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is highly recommended to model flows like this as one scenario. Please refer to the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#script-structure

> Variables set using def in the Background will be re-set before every
>   Scenario. If you are looking for a way to do something only once per
>   Feature, take a look at callonce. On the other hand, if you are
>   expecting a variable in the Background to be modified by one Scenario
>   so that later ones can see the updated value - that is not how you
>   should think of them, and you should combine your 'flow' into one
>   scenario. Keep in mind that you should be able to comment-out a
>   Scenario or skip some via tags without impacting any others. Note that
>   the parallel runner will run Scenario-s in parallel, which means they
>   can run in any order.

That said, maybe the `Background` or hooks is what you are looking for: https://github.com/intuit/karate#hooks

Comment: Thanks, I have a follow up question since I can workaround this as a single scenario.  Thanks, @Peter