# Karate; Multiple urls in a single scenario

Tags: automated-tests, karate

This is a followup from a previous question I asked [Using response data from one scenario to another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55927968/4190664)

I am looking to take information from a response in one url, then use it in a *second* url for another assertion.

Something like this:

```
Scenario: Search for asset
Given url "https://foo.bar.buzz"
When method get
Then status 200
* def responseItem = $.items[0].id // variable initialized from the response
Given url "https://foo.bar.buzz/" + responseItem + "/metadata"
// making request payload
When method put.....
```

Right now when I run this, it gets hung up on the second `Given` statement.

Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Comment: "gets hung up" is a terrible description of a problem. try harder please. if `responseItem` is a valid string it should work

Comment: I made a change to the request method (now a GET).  Instead of completely stopping, now it is telling me the request is unauthorized (an improvement).  But it's confusing because I have my header data defined in my `Background`, and I'm within the same `Scenario`.  Shouldn't the same auth be applicable for my second request?

Comment: totally depends on what you have done in the `Background`. hope someone else has the patience to help you - and this is the only advice I have left to offer: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: I figured out what I needed to do; but it was unexpected.  I have `* def headerData = { Authorization: Bearer foo/token }` in the `Background`.  I had to add `And headers headerData` _after_ making my second `Given url` statement in order to get it to work

Comment: it would not be unexpected if you read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#header

Answer (score 1):

As you probably figured out, the "Karate HTML report" will show you the request/response and headers, as long as you put DEBUG log level in your log4j config, and that will answer your question.